# Can life exist with rigid cell membranes?

Tags: science-based, creature-design, xenobiology, biochemistry

Acrylonitrile has been suggested as an alternative membrane-forming material for conditions like those on the surface of Titan, which might allow living cells to develop in liquid methane or ethane solvents. As a fairly small partially-polar molecule, it has a distinct advantage over the long-tailed phospholipids that our biology uses in that it remains liquid at liquid methane temperatures! And supposedly, the liquid nature of cellular membranes is very important for allowing cells to grow and divide, by simply manufacturing more membrane molecules which can slip into the membrane and self-organize.

Unfortunately, acrylonitrile in particular seems (according to [this article](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.aax0272)) to not actually self-assemble into micelles or azotosomes (vesicles formed from nitrogen-containing components) in Titan-like conditions! Based on [this earlier article](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.1400067), it seems that acrylonitrile, while getting the most popular press, is not the only potential option for forming low-temperature azotosomes, so all is not necessarily lost... but I have also been thinking that, for example, *plants* have rigid cell walls in addition to their fluid membranes--and somehow their cells still manage to grow and divide!

So, are fluid membranes really necessary at all? Could very low-temperature life perhaps rely on compartmentalization based on rigid, solid structures formed from larger molecules?

EDIT: Note that, while plant cell walls were an inspiration for this question, they are not actually an *answer*--plants, fungi, bacteria, and archaea all have cell walls, so clearly it's a useful structure, but they all have *different*, convergently-evolved, cell walls, and they all have very complex cell walls with a lot of cellular machinery to manage their maintenance and growth. A good answer to this question would provide a plausible explanation for how a simple rigid compartment, analogous to a cell membrane, could arise during abiogenesis--or explain why such a thing is *not* plausible after all.

Comment: *Life* with acrylonitrile cell walls is one thing, *life you can talk to* with acrylonitrile cell walls is something different. Plant life has little need nor opportunity to evolve sentience.

Comment: Can the cell membrane of acrylonitrile be softened or temporarily removed when required? You can then still have cell division as you remove the barrier when needed. The cell membrane might be replaced by acrylonitrile the moment it reaches a stable position for some time. This way you sidestep the problem.

Comment: Disclaimer: I can understand the articles, but I am NOT a biologist by any stretch of the imagination, so the following comment might be completely inane. If so, let me know and I'll delete the comment.  ***Comment:*** The more rigid the membrane wall, the less flexible the biology is when it comes to the transfer of nutrients and mutability. In fact, on a macro-scale, it might be thought of as the difference between trees and daffodils. Consequently, it would seem that life based on Acrylonitrile would have substantial limitations, such as the inability to create a pulmonary system.

Comment: Now, having said that... does it actually matter? Are you really trying to create a scientifically-valid solution? Is there anyone on Earth expert enough to actually rationalize a scientifically-perfect answer? Just how "science-based" are you looking for? I ask because I'm not a fan of "can you do this fantastic thing in real life?" questions, especially when the result will end up in some work of fiction.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Quite right. At the moment, I am concerned with *life*. *Life you can talk to* is a matter for separate, later consideration.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact Yes, I have seen previous discussions on why, e.g., animals don't have cell walls. So, maybe we end up with a world of plants and fungi--that's fine. It matters for precisely these sorts of reasons--microscopic biochemical details have macroscopic consequences for the sorts of worlds that might be encountered.

Comment: I want to ensure that, at least as of publication, I have good enough scientific rationalizations that no one can say "that definitely can't work!"--even if that results in a Larry Niven sort of situation where contradictory findings end up being published a few months later.... I left off the "hard science" tag on purpose, 'cause I doubt this can be answered absolutely authoritatively, but I want *plausibility* within the limits of what is currently known.

Comment: Are you allowing one HUGE single-celled organism? Like a turtle as a single cell, with flagella  for movement? https://microbenotes.com/flagella/

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond If there is a reasonable explanation for how such a thing might grow and reproduce, sure.

Comment: How low a temperature? Quantum-level temperatures? Tunneling across the cell enclosure?

Comment: I do not particularly see the need for complex organisms to be made up of 'cells'. All that is necessary is some mechanism for making proteins from amino acids and then chains of proteins. Nerves are in fact each made of one single cell.  The cell itself has multiple structures and operational features that are not based on cellular structures. I believe that it was only a quirk of Earth biology that complex organisms developed by combining cells instead of a single cell developing more complex functions and structures. It is much easier for the later to happen than the former.

Comment: I have argued that we need a term for assigning human characteristics to other alien life forms, the way we assign human traits to inanimate objects. Alien anthropomorphism?

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond Giant cells still add complex functions by adding internal membrane-bound organelles. I'm pretty sure compartmentalization for controlling chemical concentrations will be extremely common, if not universal.

Comment: Do you want the compartmentalization to be made of acrylonitrile as well, or only the outer containing membrane?

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond I do not care. The theoretical properties of acrylonitrile are background information, not the subject of the question.

Answer (score 4):

> the liquid nature of cellular membranes is very important for allowing cells to grow and divide, by simply manufacturing more membrane molecules which can slip into the membrane and self-organize.

First, a minor clarification of definitions: cell membranes are not liquid.  In a liquid, molecules freely move around each other, but in the case of cell membranes, molecules are ionically bound together in a fixed, but very flexible structure that allows it to flow sort of like a liquid at macroscopic scales.  But at a molecular level, they very much behave like a solid. The term you are probably looking for is [fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid).

Semantics aside, the actual detail of this question you need to focus on is if it allows more molecules to "slip into the membrane and self-organize".  A functional membrane, regardless of how ridged it is, must allow new molecules to slip in and become more of the membrane allowing an organism to grow.  Also, in order for life to evolve, the first version of a cellular membrane must be able to "self assemble" into some sort of sheet. So, your articles are not criticizing how fluid Acrylonitrile is, but how well it can self form into the repeating patterns necessary to make a contiguous membrane at all under the conditions seen on Titan.  We have examples of life on earth that have very ridged cellular walls such as plant cells or gram positive bacteria, but these structures do not naturally form into thin sheets.  They are created by life, not something life can be created from.

The thing is: it is very hard to create a cellular membrane without a flexible structure to build on.  The limiting factor is not that it must be flexible, but that it must self organizes into sheets.  However, compounds that can self-form into sheets more than 2 molecules thick can generally form into infinitely thick crystalline structures.  It is weird to think about like this, but the lipid based cell membranes we use on Earth are crystals. They are very ridged for how thick they are, but at only 2 molecules thick, they are thin enough to be flexible. [Even diamond becomes flexible when organized into thin enough of sheets.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene)  For a crystal to be ridged, it needs to naturally form in 3 dimensions instead of 2.

Since self organizing into 2-d vs 3-d lattices seems to be mutually exclusive, it may be impossible for any *single* compound to be able to form a ridged membrane.  So in order for life to exist, you need the availability of at least one compound that self organizes into 2-d sheets, then on top of that, 3-d reinforcement becomes optional using other materials.  However, you can probably not risk using a self organizing molecule for your wall or else it would simply grow in all directions.  If crystals were to self grow on the outside of a cell, they would likely expand to block off your proteins and kill the cell.  Instead, life that uses ridged cell walls build thier walls  in a controlled, non-automatic way making sure that the ridged part is the exact shape needed to not block off anything important.

Comment: Yes, but... can a rigid structure actually self-organize like that? Plant cell walls *don't*; there is a lot of cellular machinery that goes into maintaining them. So, while they may be inspiration, they are not an existence proof.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley They can self organize, but they can not be made out of a single compound.  I think the revised answer should better explain it.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley plant cell membranes however do, cells walls are outside the membrane.

Comment: @John Uh... no, they don't. Plants don't just shove cellulose monomers out through their membranes and expect them to spontaneously join up the right way. Specialized enzymes are used to expand the cellulose matrix and insert auxiliary proteins and support molecules, like silica scaffolding, expansin proteins are used to enable actively-controlled conformation changes, and there is a ton of activity using microtubules to support new wall plates under construction during cell division. They are extremely derived structures, and cannot self-organize.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley so what about that do you think disagrees with what I said?

Comment: @John If you don't disagree, then what part of what you said do you think is relevant? Plant membranes self-organize, but are not rigid, so are not relevant to the question. Plant cell walls don't self-organize, so they similarly aren't relevant.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley I think you are confusing terms, rigid is not the same as solid, and fluid is not the same as liquid. fluid solids exist. cell membranes are fluid along two axis and not fluid along the third.

Comment: @John I think the confusion is about differentiating a membrane and a wall.  A plant cell has both a cell wall and a cell membrane.  The membrane is the same sort of flexible, self-organizing structure you see in animal cell membranes.  Around the cell membrane is the rigid cell wall which is made of stuff that does not naturally self-organize into a membrane shape. What Logan is asking for is a material that self-organizes the same way that the lipids in a cell membrane do, but into a thick, ridged structure the way that plant cell walls are thick and ridged.

Comment: @Nosajimiki well humans can build rigid semipermeable membranes so it is not impossible. the problem is such a structure would not allow ingestion of large materials which is a problem since we know photosynthesis evolved long after life first evolved. So your life may not make it past the early stages.

Comment: @John Bacterial chemosynthesis uses hydrogen sulfide and methane which are both pretty tiny molecules.  So, if it a membrane is semipermeable to water, it is likely going to be semipermeable to these.

Comment: @Nosajimiki you misunderstand I mean that predators may need to evolve to keep the organisms complexity driving upwards to get to photosynthesis. large molecule exchange is needed for predation, endosymbiosis, and genetic material exchange. It is worth noting most organisms with cell walls also have large holes in them covered only by membrane, or in the case of plants lack them entirely as gametes.

Comment: @John Ah, that is a valid point, yes.